# Make two dimensional map ['NoneType' object is not iterable]

Tags: python-3.x, iterable

Just trying to get pictues to show up in a two dimensional array. What I'm trying to accomplish is everthing i wrote in dictionary, would just replace what i wrote in the other .txt file.

I really dont want to post 400 lines with codes. So I've removed a lot of the codes, just to that the same problem occurs.

def readFile(filename): 
I tried to see what the problem was, just by returning char_positions. The TKinter showed up. But only 1 picture came. and nothing else. And when i write pass instead of return I get this message

line 93, in createObjects
    for i in game_map:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
import sys
import random
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas, ALL, NW

BOARD_WIDTH = 1000 # In points px
BOARD_HEIGHT = 1000 # In points px
INFO_HEIGHT = 40 # Top info board in points px
STEP_SIZE = 40 # Size of objects in points px
MAX_RAND_POS = int(BOARD_WIDTH / STEP_SIZE) # If you want random spawns
NAMING = { 'M': "mario", 'P': "peach", 'B': "bowser", 'G': "goomba", 'K':         "koopa", 'C': "cap", 'L': "mushroom", 'V': "wall", 'Y': "wall", 'T': "gate" }
PICTURES = { # Naming from map to image path, 
    'M' : "gameImages/mario.png", "P" : "gameImages/peach.png", "B" : "gameImages/bowser.png", 
    "G" : "gameImages/goomba.png", "K" : "gameImages/koopa.png", "C" : "gameImages/cap.png","L" : "gameImages/mushroom.png",
    "V" : "gameImages/wall.png","Y" : "gameImages/wall.png" , "T" : "gameImages/gate.png"
    }

def readFile(filename):
   char_positions = {}
   with open(filename, 'r') as f:
      for y, line in enumerate(f):
          for x, c in enumerate(line):
              if not c.isspace():
                  char_positions[(x, y)] = c
pass
def main():

root = Tk() # Start graphics  window
MarioGame("level1.txt") # Start Mario Game graphics inside root window
root.mainloop() # Run graphics loop

class Board(Canvas):

def __init__(self, level): # Python class initiation function
    super().__init__(width=BOARD_WIDTH, height=BOARD_HEIGHT,
        background="black", highlightthickness=0)

    self.initGame(level)
    self.pack()


def initGame(self, level):
    '''initializes game'''

    self.inGame = True # TRUE = Not finished
    self.hasCap = False # super power
    self.jumping = False # is jumping or not
    self.jumptime = 0 # Store time when jump started here
    self.life  = 3 # Current number of lives
    self.score = 0 # Current score
    self.moveX = 0 # relative x direction coordinate
    self.moveY = 0 # relative y direction coordinate
    game_map = readFile(level) # Read in map
    self.imagesDict = self.loadImages()
    self.createObjects(game_map)
    self.bind_all("<Key>", self.onKeyPressed)
    # Debug specter mode
    self.specterMode = False # press ctrl + s to change to True


def loadImages(self):

    try: # All possible images here
        imagesDict = {}
        for key in PICTURES:
            imagesDict[key] = self.loadImage(PICTURES[key])

        # Special case for jumping mario
        self.jmario = self.loadImage("gameImages/jumpingMario.png")
        return imagesDict

    except IOError as e:

        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)

def loadImage(self, path):
    '''loads single image from the disk'''
    openImg = Image.open(path)
    openImg = openImg.resize((STEP_SIZE, STEP_SIZE), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return(ImageTk.PhotoImage(openImg))

def createObjects(self, game_map):
    '''creates objects on Canvas'''

    # Create score board
    self.create_text(30, 10, text="Score: {0}".format(self.score),
                     tag="score", fill="white")
    self.create_text(30, 30, text="Life: {0}".format(self.life),
                     tag="life", fill="white")
    # Create map
    for i in game_map: 
        map_type = game_map[i]
        xCoord = i[0]*STEP_SIZE
        yCoord = INFO_HEIGHT + i[1]*STEP_SIZE

        if map_type == "M": # special case to hide jumping mario under mario
            self.create_image(xCoord, yCoord, image=self.jmario,
                              anchor=NW, tag="jmario", state="hidden")

        self.create_image(xCoord, yCoord, image=self.imagesDict[map_type],
        anchor=NW, tag=NAMING[map_type])

class MarioGame(Frame):
def __init__(self, level):
    super().__init__() # load init from super class

    self.master.title('Mario 8-bit') # Title of window
    self.board = Board(level)
    self.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__' and len(PICTURES) > 0: # Call main if true
main() 
else: # Else  you have not done task 2 yet
print("Define PICTURES before you can start")
```

The txt file

```
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
YM                   Y
Y                    Y
YVVVVVV    VVVVVVVVVVY
Y     K    G K G    CY
Y     K K KVVVVVVVVVVY
Y                   LY
YV VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVY
YV VL      G       KLY
YV V  VVVV     G   KKY
YVGV V     VVVV      Y
YV V V G  V  G  VVVV Y
YV V V    V    V    GY
YVKV V    VG   V     Y
YV VGGG   V    V     Y
YV  G          V     Y
YVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVKVY
YL K          G      Y
Y      G             Y
Y K        G      VBVY
Y      K          VTPY
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY Y
Y                  Y Y
Y                  YTY
```

Answer (score 1):

- `readFile` doesn't return anything,
- so `game_map` (line 54) will be `None`
- so in `createObjects` (line 84), the `for i in game_map` (line 93) will try to iterate over None
- thus raising `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: Do you know how to solve this? Been trying for hours, with no success

Comment: The problem now is that it only shows me black screen. And not the two dimensional array. Here is a picture. https://i.imgur.com/LajLW86.png

Comment: That's a different problem. Open a new issue and try to explain a bit more what you tried so far.